# How can I check Kerberos Authentication as part of liveness probe?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to restart my open shift PODs whenever I see Kerberos authentication failure exception. To get that done, I need to check the Kerberos authentication as part of liveness check. Can you someone please let me know how do I check Kerberos authentication without proceeding a message to kafka broker? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple **klist** command can be used to list the Kerberos principal and tickets held in a credentials cache or the keys held in a keytab.

I also read another method here: https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/symantec-security-software/identity-security/siteminder/12-52-01/configuring/policy-server-configuration/authentication-schemes/configure-kerberos-authentication/troubleshoot-kerberos-authentication-setup.html

**Windows:**
Verify whether the keytab file is valid. Run the following command:

```
kinit -k -t keytab_file_location
respective_spn
```

This command returns no error when the keytab file is valid.

**UNIX:**
Run the following command:

```
kinit -k -t keytab_file
service_principal_name
```

If you get no errors, keytab files are fine, and the krb.conf file has valid values.

Hope this helps or at least gives you some ideas on how to test without producing a message to the topic!